# Why Can't I Print text to HTML page in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was using JQuery to load a page from the internet. When I logged it to the console, it printed all of the appropriate data, but when I tried to write it to my HTML page, it didn't work. I thought maybe since it was a JSON file, I should stringify it, but it only printed `[Object object]`. Here is an example.

```js
let url = 'https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=jpmf&interval=60min&apikey=testkey';

$.get(url, function(data) {
  text = data;
  JSON.stringify(text);
  document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = text;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="data"></div>
```

Comment: You don't assign the result of `JSON.stringify(text);` to anything, and it's redundant anyway. `data` is an object, as such you need to access its properties and output those to the HTML. See the duplicate for more info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to assign a variable to `JSON.stringify(text);` since it won't change the content of `text`. Or you can just use it straight away like :

```
document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(text);
```